# Unity Input Manager Stopped Recognizing XBox One Trigger Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controller

My 2D game is set up similarly to a twin-stick shooter, but requires the trigger on an XBox controller to be pushed down to fire. For the past couple days the trigger input was working fine, but today after setting up an enemy, the trigger input is no longer recognized. The IF statement that the trigger input control's is never entered, and weirdly enough the shooting is activated by the right d-pad, which is not set up in the input manager. I am using c# on a Mac. If you have any ideas please help.

Input Manager Settings Image:[Trigger Input Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ5WL.png)

C# Fire Controlling Code

```
 if ((Input.GetAxis("FireTrigger") > 0) && Time.time > nextFire) 
        {
            Debug.Log(Input.GetAxis("FireTrigger"));

            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bullet1, firepoint.transform.position, firepoint.transform.rotation);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your controller set up with input of xbox 360 controller instead of xbox one. Adjust input axis

https://answers.unity.com/storage/attachments/116267-xbox-one-controller-map-for-unity3d.jpg

try keeping everything the same in your code and how you have it setup but instead of 6th axis try 4th (left controller) or 5th (right) controller axis

Comment: You were correct that the axis I was using wasn't the trigger's, it was the D-Pad's. Trying every other axis, the triggers still aren't recognized. When I print the axis info to the console, it says "Unknown Xbox One Controller" instead of giving any axis info. Any ideas? Could it be a driver issue?